# Gauss-Seidel Iterative Method

Tags: numerical-methods

Can we solve not diagonally dominant matrix in Gauss-Seidel Iterative Method?
Note: We cannot make the matrix diagonally dominant.

Answer (score 1):

The Gauss-Seidel method does not necessarily require a diagonally dominant matrix. It requires that [the spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) of the **iteration matrix** be lower than 1. A diagonally dominant matrix is just a specific case of matrices  exhibiting a spectral radius lower than 1.

Moreover, this may not be achievable for any linear system of equations. Sometimes, you would need to resort to other methods (commonly, [successive over relaxation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_over-relaxation))